# How can we change a multiple running command line arguments in Linux terminal?

Tags: command-line

[According to this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/273238/how-to-run-a-command-multiple-times?newreg=e0b456bdef854144bdd10cc8c20b86bd), which said

"How to run a command multiple times?",

the correct answer was

```
for i in `seq 10`; do command; done
```

Now, If the command has an argument and every iteration, we should pass this argument to the command automatically.

How can we perform this in Linux terminal?

thanks.

Comment: How do you determine what the argument is for each command.  If you want the number of the iteration from your example, you can just run `command "$i"`, but if you need that argument to come from some other place, you'll have to tell us how to know the right argument for each iteration of the loop

Comment: Thank you @EricRenouf your suggestion of using $i is correct. How can I point to your comment as a correct answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the loop you reference in your command, you are storing the next "word" from the `seq` command in the variable `i`.  You can use that value anywhere you like, so to pass it to the command you can invoke it as `command "$i"`

You can avoid the need for the extra `seq` process with `bash` at least you can do it like

```
for ((i=1; i<=10; i++)); do
    command "$i"
done
```

or with brace expansion like

```
for i in {1..10}; do
```

or if you want to do it with POSIX compliance you could do something like

```
i=1
while [ "$i" -lt 11 ]; do
    command "$i"
    i=$((i+1))
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in `seq 10`; do command $i; done
```